# Doorbell transformer: broken if low voltage reading on multimeter?

Tags: electrical, doorbell

I put my multimeter to DC V mode and touched the two screws on our doorbell transformer but I just get a reading in millivolts which is way below the 19V it says. Does this mean it's not working or am I doing something wrong / misunderstanding?

Comment: does the door bell work?

Comment: It does not but I used AC on the multimeter per George's answer and it read 19V as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a DC device. It's AC on both the primary  and secondary windings. Doorbells operate on low voltage AC.

Comment: Did similar mistake on telephone line.  Got a reading of over 140v on reading AC instead of DC.

Comment: It's my understanding on POTS that the voltage between tip and ring, when ringing, is about 100v DC. There are DIY-er stories of getting jolted because they weren't aware.

Comment: @coderjohn  When non ringing it should be less than 50v DC, which I was expecting.  Seems multimeters read the voltages differently if not on the right scale/type of voltage.